# isReachable not working in android studio

Tags: android, xbmc

I am using XBMC android source code and now try to extract some code to new xbmc android project. When i try to connect to a ip address and check whether it is reachable using isReachable(), it is throwing a NetworkOnMainThreadException but same source code(in XBMC source code that is i downloded from the git) it is working fine,
This is the source code i'm working on

```
Handler handler = new Handler(){
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message message){
                if(message.getData().containsKey(MacAddressResolver.MESSAGE_MAC_ADDRESS)){
                    String mac = message.getData().getString(MacAddressResolver.MESSAGE_MAC_ADDRESS);
                    if(!mac.equals("")) {
                        mMacAddrView.setText(mac);
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Updated MAC for host: " + mHostView.getText().toString() + "\nto: " + mac, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                }
            }
        };


public class MacAddressResolver implements Runnable{

private String mHost = null;
private String mMac = null;
private Handler mHandler;

public static final String MESSAGE_MAC_ADDRESS = "MAC_ADDRESS";

public MacAddressResolver(String ipString, Handler handler){
    mHost = ipString;
    mHandler = handler;
}

public void run(){
    mMac = arpResolve(mHost);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(MESSAGE_MAC_ADDRESS, mMac);
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(message);
}

private String arpResolve(String host){
    System.out.println("ARPRESOLVE HOST: " + host);
    try{
        //Parse it as a proper InetAddress - it might be a hostname. We don't know yet.
        InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(host);

        //initiate some sort of traffic to ensure we get an arp entry (if we're on same subnet, that is...)
        inet.isReachable(500); //timeout of 500ms. just to trigger the arp resolution process

        //Get the official string representation of the resolved ip address
        String ipString = inet.getHostAddress();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
        String line = "";
        while(true){
            line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;
            if(line.startsWith(ipString)){
                br.close();
                System.out.println("ARPRESOLVE MAC:\n" + line);
                return line.split("\\s+")[3]; // 4th word, separated by "whitespace"
            }
        }
        br.close();
        return "";

    }catch(Exception e){

        return "";
    }

}
```

}

and i also put these two permission in my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-sdk
     android:minSdkVersion="8"
     android:targetSdkVersion="13" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I don't know, what is the problem and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NetworkOnMainThreadException exception` means that you are doing some `Networking Work` on `MainThread` (which will overload that `Thread` and throw an `Exception`).

So, you have to move that `Networking Code` to the `Background Thread`(another `thread` other then `Main Thread`).

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
 is a good example to handle such things